# how to insert text file to <list>

Tags: c#, file-io

how to insert text file to `<list>` for example text file:

```
1. this error
2. delete ?
3. add new ?
```

how to insert to  and how to retrieve message by number

for example for the number `2` i'll get `delete ?`

thanks in advance

Comment: The contents of a text file? A string? Location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Questions.txt");
var questions = new Dictionary<int, string>();
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var parts = line.Split(new[] {". "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var number = Int32.Parse(parts[0]);
    questions.Add(number, parts[1]);
}
```

To get question 2:

```
var q2 = questions[2];
```

Example:

```
class Quiz
{
    private Dictionary<int,string> _questions;

    public Quiz(string questionsFileName)
    {
        LoadQuestions(questionsFileName);
    }

    public string PoseQuestion(int number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_questions[number]);
    }

    private LoadQuestions(string fileName)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        _questions = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var parts = line.Split(new[] {". "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var number = Int32.Parse(parts[0]);
            _questions.Add(number, parts[1]);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help !, and if i ask for 2 how to retrieve  message number 2

Comment: thanks ! its work !, how to make var questions Recognized in all program forms ?

Comment: That is just a matter of decaring the questions variable at the correct scope. Just declare it as an instance variable in the class where you need the questions. Just remember that you then have to use string[] questions instead of var questions.

Comment: If this did not bother for you, can i get a sample code for this ?

Comment: I added an example. You still have to write code to use the class. But I suggest you look for that elsewhere.

Comment: cool, i got this error in this line Console.WriteLine(_question[number]); ->  The name '_question' does not exist in the current

Comment: Sorry, I made a spelling error _question should be _questions.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't compile it but if I understand you correctly you are looking for something similar to this. You should add the appropriate error handling.

```
Dictionary<int, string> map = new Dictionary<int, string>();    

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open)
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs)
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        string[] split = string.Split(".", sr.ReadLine());

        int num = int.Parse(split[0]);
        string msg = split[1];

        map.Add(num, msg);
    }
}
```